# PHP laravel - PayPal SDK cannot be called from scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-scheduler

I am unable to get PayPal payment status from scheduler. Example below:

```
function fixUnfinished()
{
    $paypalRequest = new OrdersGetRequest("<payment_id>");
    $response = app('App\Http\Controllers\PaypalController')->getPayPalClient()->execute($paypalRequest);
    ...do_something_with_the_response... (eg. dd($response); )
}
```

If I call this exact same function from a test route, everything works, the response contains the payment status and so on. example:

```
Route::get('test', function(){ app('App\Http\Controllers\PaypalController')->fixUnfinished(); });
```

However, if I call the same method from laravel scheduler (App/Console/Kernel.php), It is throwing large amounts of errors. Error sample here:

```
[2022-05-16 16:03:02] local.ERROR: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"} {"exception":"[object] (PayPalHttp\\HttpException(code: 0): {\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"error_description\":\"Client Authentication failed\"} at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\paypal\\paypalhttp\\lib\\PayPalHttp\\HttpClient.php:222)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\paypal\\paypalhttp\\lib\\PayPalHttp\\HttpClient.php(103): PayPalHttp\\HttpClient->parseResponse(Object(PayPalHttp\\Curl))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\paypal\\paypal-checkout-sdk\\lib\\PayPalCheckoutSdk\\Core\\AuthorizationInjector.php(37): PayPalHttp\\HttpClient->execute(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\\Core\\AccessTokenRequest))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\paypal\\paypal-checkout-sdk\\lib\\PayPalCheckoutSdk\\Core\\AuthorizationInjector.php(29): PayPalCheckoutSdk\\Core\\AuthorizationInjector->fetchAccessToken()
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\paypal\\paypalhttp\\lib\\PayPalHttp\\HttpClient.php(67): PayPalCheckoutSdk\\Core\\AuthorizationInjector->inject(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\\Orders\\OrdersGetRequest))
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\PaypalController.php(91): PayPalHttp\\HttpClient->execute(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\\Orders\\OrdersGetRequest))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\app\\Console\\Kernel.php(121): App\\Http\\Controllers\\PaypalController->fixUnfinished()
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Console\\Kernel->App\\Console\\{closure}()
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(36): Closure->__invoke()
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\CallbackEvent.php(118): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array, Array)
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event.php(230): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\CallbackEvent->execute(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event.php(200): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->start(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\CallbackEvent.php(77): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Event->run(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand.php(156): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\CallbackEvent->run(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand.php(115): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->runEvent(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\CallbackEvent))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\Schedule), Object(Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher), Object(NunoMaduro\\Collision\\Adapters\\Laravel\\ExceptionHandler))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Command\\Command.php(291): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(989): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(299): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Console\\Scheduling\\ScheduleRunCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(171): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Application.php(102): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AppName\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#32 {main}
"}
```

I am 100% sure the clientId and clientSecret are not the fault, because it works if called from anywhere else than the scheduler. What could be the fault?

Any help appreciated, I am quite new to Laravel.

Comment: Are you sure the dependency has resolved by the time you’re calling it in the scheduler?

Comment: When the scheduler calls it, the right config/environment needs to be set. Including anything that specifies the client id, secret, and the correct environment (sandbox or live). If any of those are incorrect, that invalid_client error is what PayPal returns.

Comment: I use the exact same thing (app('App\Http\Controllers\PaypalController')->fixUnfinished();) to call it, so there shouldn't be any dependencies needed from the scheduler.